# Multiple drawings collaboration using OpenGLES on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, concurrency, collaboration

I'm developing an app that configures:

- Hardcode an array A that store 100 points
- User can draw freestyle using his finger on screen.

Now I using OpenGLES to draw. At the period of time there are 2 actions:

- Drawing by user
- Automatic drawing from array A

I mean while user uses his finger to draw on screen, the code will automatically go through the array A to draw its points onto screen.

I configured 2 buffer named: vboId and vboId_1 to bind points from each action, vboId will bind vertex from drawing by user, and vboId_1 will bind for ones from array A. Following is the drawing code (assume all the initializes for openGLES context, frame buffer, render buffer, etc are ready)

```
- (void)renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end isOwner:(BOOL)owner {
    static GLfloat*     vertexBuffer = NULL;
    static NSUInteger   vertexMax = 64;
    NSUInteger          vertexCount = 0,
                        count,
                        i;

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);

    // Convert locations from Points to Pixels
    CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
    start.x *= scale;
    start.y *= scale;
    end.x *= scale;
    end.y *= scale;

    // Allocate vertex array buffer
    if(vertexBuffer == NULL)
        vertexBuffer = malloc(vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));

    // Add points to the buffer so there are drawing points every X pixels
    count = MAX(ceilf(sqrtf((end.x - start.x) * (end.x - start.x) + (end.y - start.y) * (end.y - start.y)) / kBrushPixelStep), 1);
    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if(vertexCount == vertexMax) {
            vertexMax = 2 * vertexMax;
            vertexBuffer = realloc(vertexBuffer, vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));
        }

        vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 0] = start.x + (end.x - start.x) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
        vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 1] = start.y + (end.y - start.y) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
        vertexCount += 1;
    }

    // Draw
    if (drawing_by_user) {
        // Draw vertex from user
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexCount*2*sizeof(GLfloat), vertexBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
        glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brushTexture.id);

        glUseProgram(program[PROGRAM_POINT_USER].id);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, (int)vertexCount);
    } else {
        // draw vertex automatically
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId_1);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexCount*2*sizeof(GLfloat), vertexBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
        glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brushTexture.id);

        glUseProgram(program[PROGRAM_POINT_AUTO].id);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, (int)vertexCount);
    }


    // Display the buffer
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

Actually this code works, 2 actions happen but it don't like my expectation. While drawing, sometimes it stuck, leaking, loses a few points, not smooth, and make user experience bad.

If just draw by user or draw from array A is ok, it's smooth

I suppose I can not bind 2 actions to the frame buffer and render buffer at the same time, concurrency or I have to implement with some higher mechanism

**UPDATED 1:**
I realized that the problem seems to cause by application can not received touch events while auto drawing points on array A. I mean some functions touchBegan, touchMove and touchEnd are not recognized while drawing points on array A.

It's so weird, if just drawing one of them, it works, I don't see the difference, drawing just one of them also do these actions (bind buffer, render buffer...), drawing both of them still using these functions. Why these touch events not be fired.

Can anyone help me

Comment: How do you call renderLineFromPoint method? Do you know how RunLoop works?

Comment: @KazukiSakamoto, I call renderLineFromPoint method on touch events methods, like on touchesBegan, touchesMove and touchesEnd. I wonder Runloop will capture these touch event, right?

Comment: Eh, that's why. How do you call the method for array A?

Comment: @KazukiSakamoto, actually I have a timer added into Runloop at mode NSRunloopCommonMode and fired every 0.1f. Every time the timer fires, I select points on array A and call the above method renderLineFromPoint to draw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend you to read documents about using OpenGL ES in iOS application. For example,

- iPhone 3D Programming http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001814/index.html
- OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Because you called EAGLContext -presentRenderbuffer: from touchesBegan or so on. It's pretty inefficient way.

From Apple document "A GLKit View Controller Animates OpenGL ES Content"

> By default, a GLKView object renders its contents on demand. That said, a key advantage to drawing with OpenGL ES is its ability to use graphics processing hardware for continuous animation of complex scenes—apps such as games and simulations rarely present static images. For these cases, the GLKit framework provides a view controller class that maintains an animation loop for the GLKView object it manages. This loop follows a design pattern common in games and simulations, with two phases: update and display. Figure 3-2 shows a simplified example of an animation loop.

[image: Figure 3-2 animation loop]

Usually application using OpenGL ES uses an animation loop like this GLKit document. In **update** phase, updating positions of 3D objects, motion of 3D models, calculating the next point of lines, some sort of things. In **display** phase, the app uses OpenGL ES APIs to render the 3D objects, 3D models, lines, such kind of stuff.

So you might need to implement as the following.

- In touch events, keep the position of the touch in the memory. Don't render anything, don't use OpenGL ES APIs at this point.
- In update phase, decide which point to render, the position of the user touch, or, the position from the array for drawing automatically. And then prepare the vertices data. You don't need timer at all.
- In draw phase, render the lines using OpenGL ES APIs. You can find a way to reduce rendering time, for example, keep the rendered buffer, or something.
- At the end of draw phase, call EAGLContext -presentRenderbuffer:. If you uses GLKit or some sort of framework, it is automatically called from the framework. You don't need to call it.

Comment: Thank @KazukiSakamoto, I will try using GLKit to make my work simpler. I will update my question after my attempt with GLKit

Comment: You will update your question? It doesn't make sense at all. I recommend you to accept this answer, and then if you have further questions, you can create new questions any time.